# MATLAB Error Message (function definitions)

Tags: matlab

I am getting the following error when I type in CalculateIntegral(2,5) into the MATLAB Command Window:

??? Error: File: CalculateIntegral.m Line: 2 Column: 1
Function definitions are not permitted at the prompt or in scripts.

I am not sure how to resolve this error. Thanks.

```
    clear all;
    function g = CalculateIntegral(s,N)
    a=0; 
    b=1;
    h=(b-a)/N;
    x = 0:h:1;
    g = ff(x).*exp(-s*x);

    % compute the exact answer of the integral
    exact_answer=antiderivative(b,s)-antiderivative(a,s);

    % compute the composite trapezoid sum
    If=0;
    for i=1:(N-1)
        If=If+g(i)*h;
    end;
    If=If+g(1)*h/2+g(N)*h/2;
    If;
```

Comment: Why does it output a vector when I run it now? I have semicolons after everything.

Comment: Why did you remove the code from your question?

Comment: I posted another question with the code.

Comment: you should still keep the code here as well, since the question makes much less sense without it...

Comment: You should link **[your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643837/matlab-function-solving-an-error) about the same code** so we can see the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a `clear all` before your function definition (and you don't need one). Just remove that first line to make your code work. [MATLAB functions](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/function.html) need to be by themselves in their own file, named like the function (`CalculateIntegral.m` in your case).

Comment: Would there be a way to include the rest of the algorithm in the same file?

Comment: The way you wrote it, *all* of your code is the function. I'm not sure what you mean by "rest of the algorithm"

Comment: Thanks. Why does it output a vector when I run it now? I have semicolons after everything.