# Plotting graph error (values not showign up)

Tags: matlab

How do I plot the value of `Approximation - Answer` as `s` varies in the code below? If you look at my code below, you can see the method I used (I put it in a separate file).

However, it does not show me a graph from `1` to `1000`. Instead the graph is from `999` to `1001` and does not have any points on it.

```
for s = 1:1000
    error = LaplaceTransform(s,5) - (antiderivative(1,s)-antiderivative(0,s));
end
plot(s,error);
title('Accuracy of Approximation');
xlabel('s');
ylabel('Approximation - Exact Answer');
```

The functions used:

```
function g = LaplaceTransform(s,N);
% define function parameters
a=0; 
b=1;
h=(b-a)/N;
x = 0:h:1;
% define function
g = ff(x).*exp(-s*x);

% compute the exact answer of the integral
exact_answer=antiderivative(b,s)-antiderivative(a,s)
% compute the composite trapezoid sum
If=0;
for i=1:(N-1)
    If=If+g(i).*h;
end;
If=If+g(1).*h/2+g(N).*h/2;
If
```

with

```
function fx=ff(x)
fx=x;
```

and

```
function fx=antiderivative(x,s);
fx= (-exp(-s*x)*(s*x+1))/(s^2);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you are overwriting the `error` variable in each iteration. Instead store the values in a vector: `error(s) = ...` and plot the result as `plot(1:1000,error)`. On another note, ERROR is a built-in function, so avoid using it as variable name

Comment: In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
 I must be the same.

Error in ==> Graph at 2
difference(s) = LaplaceTransform(s,50) -
(antiderivative(1,s)-antiderivative(0,s));

Comment: Not sure how to fix that error when I run this code: for s = 1:1000
difference(s) = LaplaceTransform(s,50) - (antiderivative(1,s)-antiderivative(0,s));
end

plot(1:1000,difference);

Comment: I assume you are the owner of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643837/matlab-function-solving-an-error).. Well some of the previous problems still exist: you should return `If` not `g` from the `LaplaceTransform` function

Comment: The function itself is working perfectly now and is calculating the correct values. The problem I am having now is graphing.

Comment: @Amro: Just noticed that you have found the issues as well. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @user983202: please edit your question, post the modifications you made, and state the problem is exactly (with any error messages you get)

Comment: @Jonas: you don't need to do that :)

Comment: @user983202: In fact, you had yet [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667143/matlab-error-message-function-definitions) with the exact same problem... Why are you asking for help if you are then ignoring it?

Comment: @user983202: please don't sabotage your own questions by deleting [all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643837/matlab-function-solving-an-error) [the](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667143/matlab-error-message-function-definitions) [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667654/suppressing-output-matlab) (you do know they can be reverted back then locked??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following

```
for s = 1:1000
    error = LaplaceTransform(s,5) - (antiderivative(1,s)-antiderivative(0,s));
end
plot(s,error);
```

already has several issues. The two main ones are that `error` is getting overwritten at each iteration, as @Amro has pointed out, and that `s`, your loop variable, is a scalar.

Thus, you need to write

```
difference = zeros(1000,1); %# preassignment is good for you
for s = 1:1000
    difference(s) = LaplaceTransform(s,5) - (antiderivative(1,s)-antiderivative(0,s));
end
plot(1:1000,difference);
```

There is another error in the `LaplaceTransform` function

```
function g = LaplaceTransform(s,N);
[...]
g = ff(x).*exp(-s*x); %# g is an array

[...]
If %# If is calculated, but not returned.
```

I assume you want to write

```
function If = LaplaceTransform(s,N);
```

instead, because otherwise, you try to assign the array `g` to the scalar `difference(s)`.

Comment: I get this error:
???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
 I must be the same.

Error in ==> Graph at 3
    difference(s) = LaplaceTransform(s,5) -
    (antiderivative(1,s)-antiderivative(0,s));

Comment: I also don't want if to be the function. g is the function that I want and when I run it, the program works perfectly.

Comment: Well, it seems to work a bit better now that I changed the function to if.